# mod_wsgi hangs on RuntimeWarning: divide by zero

Tags: python, apache, warnings, mod-wsgi

I have some python code that may result in a division by 0, but it runs correctly in a python (3.2) interpreter. However, if I try to run it using mod_wsgi, it simply hangs without an error and the request is not served.

Warning in interpreter (output is correct): `pathwayAnalysis.py:30: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars`

Does anybody know what the correct way to run this using mod_wsgi would be?

The code is below. Both difference and size are numpy float arrays of length 2. Either float in `difference` may be 0 (but not both). Adding `difference += 0.0001` before this makes it run correctly, but is not a nice solution since the output is not accurate:

```
if abs(difference[0] / difference[1]) > (size[0] / size[1]):
    ratio = abs(size[0] / difference[0])
else: ratio = abs(size[1] / difference[1])
for i in range(len(base)):
    result.append(base[i] + difference[i] * ratio/2)
return array(result)
```

Doing the following does not work:

```
try:
    cond = abs(difference[0] / difference[1]) > (size[0] / size[1])
except RuntimeWarning:
    cond = True
# hangs before this point
if cond:
    '''as above'''
```

Some test code (using either one of the `difference` definitions):

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    from numpy import array

    size = array([10., 10.])

    difference = array([115., 0.]) # hangs
    difference = array([115., 10.]) # returns page with text 'Yes.'

    if abs(difference[0]/difference[1]) > (size[0]/size[1]):
        output = 'Yes.'
    else:
        output = 'No.'

    status = '200 OK'

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),\
        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]
```

Comment: Can you indicate what version of mod_wsgi you are using and also provide a complete working self contained WSGI hello world with the code in it that fails. That way can easily test rather than guess whether copied the intent of your code correctly. So, start with example in http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide#WSGI_Application_Script_File and add your code to it to make it fail. Example will need to be made Python 3 compatible though as currently not.

Comment: I am using mod_wsgi-3.3.0. I will update later with a hello world example, but the program runs fine if the conditional is changed to `if (abs(difference[0]) / (abs(difference[1]) + 0.001)) > (size[0] / size[1]):`, this just seems a messy solution which doesn't address the hang.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton the hello world example shows the same behavior. It is python 3 compatible as far as I can tell?

Comment: Can you download latest mod_wsgi 3.4 source code as detail in http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ChangesInVersion0304 and see if the newer version makes a difference?

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Just tried the hello world code with the new version, no change. If it is any help, I get `[warn] child process [number] still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM` three times and then `[error] child process [number] still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL` on restarting apache.

Comment: What if your code is not made dependent on numpy? I would hazard to guess this is a numpy issue and not mod_wsgi. Specifically, what happens if you force use of main interpreter by setting 'WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}'? Some packages are notorious for not working in sub interpreters and will lock up at times. That directive forces use of main interpreter.

Comment: BTW, your test script is not WSGI/Python 3.X compliant. mod_wsgi is a bit lax right now and lets through invalid stuff. The output should be bytes and not native string (Unicode).

Comment: That config setting did it. Does this setting have any other effects I should be aware of? If you add it as an answer I can select it...

Comment: The restriction is that you can often only run one site now in that configuration. This is because it isn't possible to run multiple Django sites for example in the same interpreter. Your mileage may vary with other frameworks. Use daemon mode of mod_wsgi to separate applications into separate processes and then you will be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some third party packages for Python which use C extension modules, and this includes numpy,  will only work in the Python main interpreter and cannot be used in sub interpreters as mod_wsgi by default uses. The result can be thread deadlock, incorrect behaviour or processes crashes. These is detailed in:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Python_Simplified_GIL_State_API

The workaround is to force the WSGI application to run in the main interpreter of the process using:

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

If running multiple WSGI applications on same server, you would want to start investigating using daemon mode because some frameworks don't allow multiple instances to run in same interpreter. This is the case with Django. Thus use daemon mode so each is in its own process and force each to run in main interpreter of their respective daemon mode process groups.